# XML digital signatures in Perl

Tags: xml, perl, digital-signature

I'm trying to digitally sign XML in Perl using the [`Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA`](https://metacpan.org/module/Crypt%3a%3aOpenSSL%3a%3aRSA) module. I'm loading a private key from a file. The private key was generated from a keystore using Java.

Below is my Perl code:

```
my $private = 'my_priv.key';
my $private_key = read_file( $private );
print "my private key text is\n", $private_key;
```

Output, not putting the entire key here, just the few first lines :-)

```
> -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- MIICdgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAmAwggJcAgEAAoGBAKAuqJ1ZkxHZStfSt0CdEsaSYuLO
> 6zDiTpt60asVLWpLe2bf...
```

```
my $rsa_priv = Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->new_private_key($private_key);
print "my private key is\n",$rsa_priv->get_private_key_string();
```

Output:

```
> -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
> MIICXAIBAAKBgQCgLqidWZMR2UrX0rdAnRLGkmLizusw4k6betGrFS1qS3tm3+97
> wMvFXCx0Od8eb
```

The results of `$private_key` and `$rsa_priv->get_private_key_string()` are different. Is it supposed to behave like that?

Has anyone been able to sign XML using `Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA`?

edit:

i'm using java code to extract the private key, code is as below
    `KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");

```
keypass = sPass.toCharArray();

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(store);
ks.load(fis, sPass.toCharArray());
fis.close();

String eol = System.getProperty("line.separator");

Key k = ks.getKey(alias, keypass);

System.out.println("....Generating the Private Key.....");
String encKey = new BASE64Encoder().encode(k.getEncoded());
System.out.println("Encoded Key: " + encKey);
BufferedWriter myKey = null;
myKey = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(alias + "_priv.key"));
myKey.write("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----" + eol);
myKey.write(encKey + eol);
myKey.write("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----");
myKey.close();
System.out.println("....Private Key Generated.....");`
```

using both java and perl because the xmls i'm trying to sign are in perl (it's a whole big system) and the keystore is in java.

First time digitally signing anything and my digitally signed xml is not authenticating at all to the recipient system

Comment: Perhaps it might help if you add the `keytool` command used to generate the Java private key.

Comment: just added the code used to generate the private key

Answer (score 2):

> The results of `$private_key;` and `$rsa_priv->get_private_key_string();` are different, is this supposed to behave like that?

Yes, the input is a X509 key, the output is an RSA key. `openssl rsa -in my_priv.key` gives the same result.

If you have no idea about this stuff, you are better off with a high-level library.

- [XML-Sig](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Sig)
- [Net-SAML2](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-SAML2)

Comment: i had tried working with XML-Sig but it did not work with my application, the resulting xml was not being authenticated, thought i'd use this approach to better understand the whole process, i'm a bit new on digital signatures and openssl

Comment: @qateey and @daxim, `XML::Sig` is *not* a good recommendation: http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=XML-Sig+0.22, `Net::SAML2', on the other hand: http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=Net-SAML2+0.17

Comment: Axeman, you have to learn to read the summarised automated test reports properly. You should be suspucious about an all-red result! In the case of XML-Sig, there's just a dependency missing. This masks a real problem with DSA and PKCS#8 keys, but as long qateey keeps to RSA keys, the module is perfectly servicable.

Comment: @daxim, found out that my issue is all because of the format of the keys i'm using, with XML::SIG and Crypt::OpenSSl::RSA, keys are converted to rsa format, however the system i'm sending requests to expects signatures created using pkcs#8 format keys, is there a module i can use that would enable signing data using pkcs#8 keys instead of rsa